# How to push image data to couchdb using node.js

Tags: node.js, couchdb

How should i push image data to couchdb using nodejs through JSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really understand what you were asking so assumed the most common scenario of inserting an attachment into couchdb:

```
 var db      = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984/test');
 var request = require('request');

 // {} for empty body as parameter is required but will be piped in
 request.get("http://nodejs.org/logo.png").pipe(
   db.attachment.insert("new", "logo.png", {}, "image/png"));
```